# How do I get the slimy clumps out of my bisque?

Tags: substitutions

I used potato starch instead of cornstarch, as a thickener and forgot to make a slurry first.  Unfortunately, the bisque isn't a pureed bisque, it's mushroom, celery and onion.
After I realized my mistake, I then added more as a slurry and was able to properly thicken it.
But it still has the slimy clumps, very unappetizing. How do I get the slimy clumps out without pureeing the whole thing?

Comment: Emily, there is no question here.  If you would like a response, please edit your post so that it is in the form of a question.  You might also try to search first (using the search bar above), to see if your question was previously asked.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option might be to pick out as many of the vegetable chunks as you feel reasonable, then puree the rest.  You'll end up with a thicker soup body, and fewer vegetable chunks, but it might not be a bad tradeoff to get rid of the lumps.

Or (depending on amount and proportion of liquid to vegetable) strain the liquid out, manually add the vegetable chunks from your strainer to the soup, and either discard lumps left in the strainer or puree them with leftover vegetable chunks (depending on how much patience you have for sorting) with reserved liquid.

Last option - if the lumps are pretty visible, you can pick them out when you see them - for example, when serving from a pot into a dish, or each time you pull it out of the fridge.  If the soup is liquidy you could try scooping up spoonfuls of broth with as many lumps as you can, and ladling them into a strainer held right over the pot, so the liquid will flow right back in and only the lumps get held back.

These last are really annoying, and a lot of work, but if it's really bothering you it does help... I did something similar with a dish once, though it was for woody herb bits, since I didn't want to waste a pot-full of food.

Comment: Those are great suggestions.  I have a lot of patience, so I may portion it out and see which works best.  At first I thought it was little bits of mushroom, but I knew I had sliced them larger because that's my preference.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, neither of which will be all that helpful given your situation.  In general, you can attempt to strain out the lumps, or puree the liquid.  Otherwise, chalk it up to a lesson learned.

Comment: I didn't thicken it a whole lot, so I think I may be able to strain the bulk of them out.  I would've never thought to strain it.  I was so dismayed because I made a gallon.  I've made the recipe so many times, it's second nature, so the mistake was just me not paying attention.  Thank you!